# How to Implement Postgresql Materialized Views in Azure SQL/MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, materialized-views, azure-sql

I'm currently working on `Postgresql` migration to `Azure SQL` database and needed to convert Postgres materialized views into `Azure SQL`. I cannot used `SQL server` indexed views since existing Postgres materialized views are sourcing from other views and are using `UNION` and `AGGREGATE FUNCTIONS` which are limitations of indexed views. My initial plan is to create physical table that will hold same data as the view. Is there any alternative way of how to refresh the data on the table without recreating the table itself?

Please advise.

Comment: Indexed Views, in SQL Server, *are* materialised views. If you can't use Indexed views, you can't use materialised views in SQL Server.

Comment: Maybe you don't actually need an indexed view? Have you tried creating a regular view and testing your code to determine if that (plus whatever indexing is missing from the base tables) is sufficient?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! " My initial plan is to create physical table that will hold same data as the view." - if you can't index view than maybe it's the only possible way. "Is there any alternative way of how to refresh the data on the table" - of course it's better to minimize recalculations and modifications for aggregate tables. Show example of your data, so it will be possible to answer your question more precisely

Comment: Views can get expensive, especially with large datasets.  Have you considered a Table-Valued Function?   With the appropriate set of parameters, you can create a more efficient and flexible environment.

Comment: Note that `SUM` and `COUNT_BIG` *are* allowed in indexed views

Comment: Post the view, query and table schemas instead of assuming you need a materialized view in the first place. SQL Server has powerful features that are missing from PostgreSQL, eg columnstore indexes. Using `UNION` smells like hand-written partitioning, something *not* needed with SQL Server in many cases. Table partitioning is available in all supported SQL Server versions and editions, even Express and LocalDB